# Mariadb Explain statement estimating high number of rows that would be found during lookup

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

I have a table with 32 columns of which 6 rows are primary keys and 2 more column are indexed.

[image: Table indexes]

Explain statement provides the below output

[image: Explain output]

I have observed that, everytime the number of rows in the explain statement increases, the select query takes seconds to retrieve data from DB. The above select query returned only 310 rows but it had to scan 382546 rows.

Time taken was calculated by enabling mariadb's slow query log.

Create table query

[image: Create table-1]

[image: Create table-1 continued]

I would like to understand the incorrectness in the table or query which is considerably slowing down the select query execution.

Comment: You appear to have fewer than 400,000 rows. It would be unusual to introduce partitioning of fewer than a million rows, and even then, we'd want to understand the need for doing so.

Comment: And please don't post pictures of text (with the possible exception of the result of the EXPLAIN itself)

Comment: Additionally, there also seems to be a strange inconstency in the name of your first column (`run_id` instead of `lcr_run_id`) in your picture, not sure what this is about (or if it's still too early for me). Also, please run your query without the last `and country_code =1506`, that will be the number of rows scanned (which might be lower and will include the partitioning).

Comment: The highlighted number says that the combination of ZONE, and the 5 columns before it, has an estimated 35M distinct values.  (The number is not very useful.)

Comment: Won't that HASH include `0`, but not `9`?

Answer (score 1):

Your row is relatively large (around 300bytes, depending on the content of your varchar columns). Using the primary key means (for InnoDB) that MySQL will read the whole row. Assuming the estimate of 400k rows is right (which it probably isn't, but you can check by removing the `and country_code = 1506` from your query to get a better count), MySQL may end up reading more than 100mb from disk, which reasonably can take several seconds.

Adding a proper index should fix this, in your case I would suggest `(country_code, lcr_run_id, tier_type)` (which would, with your primary key, actually be the same as just `(country_code)`).

If most of your queries have that form (e.g. use at least these three columns for lookup), you could think about changing the order of your primary key to start with those three columns, it should give you another speedboost. That operation will take some time though.

Comment: Also, the lack of partition pruning _hurts_ performance -- It must check each partition and combine the results.

Answer (score 1):

Hash partitioning is useless for performance, get rid of it.  Ditto for subpartitioning.

Specifying which partition to use defeats the purpose of letting the Optimizer do it for you.

You simply need `INDEX(tier_type, lcr_run_id, country_code)` with the columns in any desired order.

Plan A:  Have the `PRIMARY KEY` *start* with those 3 columns (again, the order is not important)

Plan B:  Have a "secondary" index with those 3 columns, but *not* being the same as the start of the PK.  (This index could have more columns on the end; let's see some more queries to advise further.)

Either way, it will scan only 310 rows if you also get rid of all partitioning.  (Hence, resolving your "returned only 310 rows but it had to scan 382546 rows".  Anyway, the '382546' may have been a poor estimate by Explain.)

The important issue here is that indexing works with the *leftmost* columns in the `INDEX`.  (The PK is an index.)  Your `SELECT` had a match on the first 2 columns, but `country_code` came later in the list, and the intervening columns were not tested with `=`.

The three 35M values makes me wonder if the PK is over-specified.  For example, if a "zone" is comprised of several "countries", then "zone" is irrelevant in specifying the PK.

The table has only 382K rows, but it is much fatter than it needs to be.  Partitioning has a *lot* of overhead.  Also, most columns have (I think) much bigger datatypes than needed.  `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes; `INT` takes 4 bytes.  For example, if there are only a small number of "zones", use `TINYINT UNSIGNED`, which takes only 1 byte (and allows values 0..255).  (See also other 'int' variants.)

Oops, I missed something else.  Since `zone` is not in the `WHERE`, it can't even get past the primary partitioning.